# Undefined function openssl_encrypt() in Encrypter.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, php-openssl

I get the following error:

> Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() in Encrypter.php line 73

It may seem obvious, but OpenSSL extension is enabled in my config, this error occurs only when using `artisan serve`, looked through config and it is enabled.

Did some research:
Copied the following code in the `artisan` file

```
$loaded = extension_loaded('openssl');
var_dump($loaded);die();
```

And it returned `true`. But when I copy the same code into `/public/index.php` it returns `false`.

So I assumed that the `openssl` extension is enabled in `php-cli`, but for some reason it gets disabled after reaching the bootstrap file.

*And I am using UniServer if someone is interested.

Comment: Where did you execute the `die(var_dump($loaded));' command?

Comment: In the artisan file

Comment: So I guess you used command line interface to execute the artisan command. I suspect that you have a different configuration for cli and cgi. Can you execute phpinfo() from your browser (first line after <?php index.php) and confirm that open ssl is loaded and enabled?

Comment: Yes, I used artisan serve, and when opened in the browser, got the error. CLI is loading php-cli.ini file, in which the extension is enabled too

Comment: My point is that if the openssl is truly not enabled, why do I get true on checking `extension_loaded` in the start of the app?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use phpinfo() and find openssl there and see if it is really "enabled"

Comment: No, it does not show enabled in phpinfo()

Comment: Maybe it is not enabled in apache's php.ini file?

Comment: It seems that the php-cli.ini is not loaded in phpinfo(), but what can cause this ?

Comment: It's pretty normal to have different php.ini files for different sapis.

Comment: I think There should be two different php.ini files in your server configuration

Comment: There are indeed. But the problem is that when I execute any php file using cli, the openssl is loaded (and the php-cli.ini too), but when executing artisan serve, the config file is not loaded, so does the extension.

Comment: CLI stands for Command Line Interface. When executing things from the `php` command-line, php-cli.ini will be loaded. When you run `php artisan serve`, the serve itself is being executed from cli, hence open-ssl enabled, but when accessing your project from a browser with the address provided by the `php artisan serve`, the `php.ini` (non-cli) will be loaded.

Comment: OK, then how can I enable it? because no php.ini files are loaded in the end.

Comment: @gagvirus as I wrote 31 minutes ago, can you please find the php.ini file used by the apache server and enable open ssl there?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, does the apache run when using cli?

Comment: As I found out php was not loading the php-cli.ini file, instead it was looking for one in C:\Windows folder. So I copied the contents of php-cli.ini to C:\Windows\php.ini.

Answer (score 6):

Had same issue on Apache 2.4, PHP7, Fresh Laravel 5.3 on a Windows.
My Apache error log showed

```
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\wamp\\php\\ext\\php_openssl.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1.\r\n in Unknown on line 0"
```

Fixed it by copying libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from PHP-root folder to Apache/bin folder and restarted Apache.

Comment: "copying libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from PHP-root folder to Apache/bin folder and restarted Apache" solved my problem.